# Implode Multi Dimensional Array to a single comma separated list in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

If I have an array like:

```
Array ( [0] => abcdef )
Array ( [0] => abcdef [1] => abcdef )
Array ( [0] => abcdef [1] => abcdef [2] => abcdef )
Array ( [0] => abcdef [1] => qwerty )
```

And want to create a comma separated list like:

```
abcdef, abcdef, abcdef, abcdef, abcdef, abcdef, abcdef, qwerty
```

How would I do this?

When I try and implode the array like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)){ 
    $row2 = $row['scholarshipid']; 
    $newarray = unserialize($row2);
    $unique_array = array_unique($newarray, SORT_REGULAR);
    $commaList = implode(', ', $unique_array);
    echo "$commaList";
    //print_r($newarray); 
} 

$commaList = implode(', ', $unique_array);
```

I get:

```
abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef, qwerty
```

Comment: Is this code in a loop?

Comment: Yes, it is. while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)){

Comment: Then please show us your code where and how you create the arrays.

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)){
     
$row2 = $row['scholarshipid'];  

$newarray = unserialize($row2);

$unique_array = array_unique($newarray, SORT_REGULAR);

$commaList = implode(', ', $unique_array);

echo "$commaList";

//print_r($newarray);

}

Comment: That array description looks rather odd, can you do a `print_r($unique_array);` and edit that into your question please

Comment: @TomCanfarotta Why the hell is sql a problem here, if the question does not even contain a single line of sql code?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438714/implode-multi-dimensional-array-to-a-single-comma-separated-list-in-php#comment56618427_34438714) it turns out that the output which you show us comes from a loop. So you first have to collect all arrays in each iteration into 1 variable, which you then can implode, e.g.

```
$result = [];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)){
    $row2 = $row['scholarshipid'];
    $newarray = unserialize($row2);
    $unique_array = array_unique($newarray, SORT_REGULAR);
    $result = array_merge($result, $unique_array);
}

echo implode(",", $result);
```

Comment: @TomCanfarotta You're welcome. Also see: [tour] to get a quick overview of the site.

Answer (score -2):

you can do it like this **UPDATE**

```
$temp = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)){ 
    $row2 = $row['scholarshipid']; 
    $newarray = unserialize($row2);
    $temp = array_merge($temp, $newarray);

}
$commaList = implode(', ', $temp);
print_r($commaList);
```

and it's all done :P

Comment: The problem is the array's are coming from the db and the amount will not be constant.

Comment: Please read the question properly, its a multidimensional array, not different arrays

Comment: @TomCanfarotta  i've read the question but the result is not associative array so when you merge it it gives you two array in one array in this case it will merge all arrays that comes after the while loop implode the new array

Comment: the merge array it make all your results in one array, after that the implode is making the $commaList as you want

Comment: I know what the code does. I asked where the difference is to mine answer after the update.

Comment: @Rizier123 i think there is no diff

Comment: @Rizier123 i think the only diff is that you use the array_unique to unique the values :)